# CakePHP 3 to Progressive Web App Back-End

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js, cakephp, progressive-web-apps

I have a web application that is set up in CakePHP 3 WAMP environment. I would like to set it up as a Progressive Web App. So have the existing Model/ Controller act as an API that is exposed to a PWA framework like Angular, (P)React, Vue.js. Where can I find a clear guide/ tutorial on what steps to take to turn my existing application into a functioning backend API?

Any tips from someone who has done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go!

**Read:**

1. **[REST](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/rest.html)**
2. **[RequestHandlerComponent](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent)**
3. **[Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#resource-routes)**